# Opposite enum values TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

Is it possible to make an enum with two values that when one is used with a `!` operator returns the other one? I dont know if that makes sense, so here's what  i want but with code:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue
}
```

`!MyEnum.FirstValue => MyEnum.SecondValue`

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
 enum MyEnum {
   FirstValue = 1,
   SecondValue = ~FirstValue
 }
```

You could use the XOR on a numeric enum. To invert, just use `~`.

```
 ~MyEnum.FirstValue === MyEnum.SecondValue
 ~~MyEnum.FirstValue === MyEnum.FirstValue
```

Alternatively you could use a lookup object:

```
 enum MyEnum { FirstValue = 1; SecondValue = 2 }

 const invert = {
   [MyEnum.FirstValue]: MyEnum.SecondValue,
   [MyEnum.SecondValue]: MyEnum.FirstValue
 };

 invert[MyEnum.FurstValue] === MyEnum.SecondValue
```

Comment: Are booleans supported? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20MyEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FirstValue%20%3D%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SecondValue%20%3D%20false%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: You can only use strings with enums, not booleans

Comment: @adiga whoops, I thought they were supported.